# nuget: Deploy T4 files without reference

Tags: tfs, nuget

We are currently using some shared T4 files in multiple projects. These files now exist in various git repositories and therefore we want to distribute them via nuget.

Creating a nuget package with these files as content works fine but then I get a separate copy of these T4 in each project. Unfortunately we still have a high project count per repository and therefore we would get hundrets of file duplicates. This slows down clone and checkout operations.

I tried to find a similiar approach to what Nunit3TestAdapter does: Just deploy the files in the libs folder of the nuget package but do not change anything in the project.

This way we can have only a single copy of these shared files.

How do I manage this in the nuspec file? As soon as I do not have files to be added to the project I get the message "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Here is my current nuspec file (The $ variables are replaced when we build the package via TFS):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>$SolutionName$</id>
        <version>$Version$</version>
        <authors>$SSH$</authors>
        <owners>$SSH$</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Softship common T4 templates. Current Version: $Version$</description>
        <copyright>Copyright $date$</copyright>

    <!-- Do not list this as dependency of other nuget -->
    <developmentDependency>true</developmentDependency>

    </metadata>

    <files>
        <file src="build/net35/MultipleOutputHelper.ttinclude" target="build\net35" />
        <file src="build/net35/GenerateTextMessages.ttinclude" target="build\net35" />
        <file src="build/net35/DataModelRelationsGenerator.ttinclude" target="build\net35" />
        <file src="build/net35/DataModelGenerator.ttinclude" target="build\net35" />         
    </files>

</package>
```

Comment: What version of NuGet are you using? I suspect you may have to put a dummy `lib/net35/_._` placeholder to allow it to install if NuGet does not consider the build folder enough to allow the install to continue. Various .NET Core NuGet packages use this technique - no assembly is provided but it allows the NuGet package to be installed into a project. Example is System.Xml.Document. The `_._` is just an empty file.

Comment: I tried that `<files>
   <file src="tools/MultipleOutputHelper.ttinclude" target="tools" />
   <file src="tools/GenerateTextMessages.ttinclude" target="tools" />
   <file src="tools/DataModelRelationsGenerator.ttinclude" target="tools" />
   <file src="tools/DataModelGenerator.ttinclude" target="tools" />   
  </files>` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually works for me:

```
<files>
        <file src="tools/MultipleOutputHelper.ttinclude" target="tools" />
        <file src="tools/GenerateTextMessages.ttinclude" target="tools" />
        <file src="tools/DataModelRelationsGenerator.ttinclude" target="tools" />
        <file src="tools/DataModelGenerator.ttinclude" target="tools" />         
    </files>
```